# unresolved external with static and trait classes

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a trait class like this

```
template <int Size, typename T>
class Traits<Vector<Size, T>>
{
    enum {ElementCount = Size};
};
```

This works fine, but I get lots of warnings with GCC when comparing the size from different trait instances. So I thought I would use `static const int ElementCount` instead, but now GCC complains about unresolved externals (i.e. `ElementCount`) not found. How am I supposed to resolve this? I certainly can't instantiate the Traits class for every single combination. Why does the GCC see this correctly with enums, but not with const static?

Comment: Can you post a minimally somewhat working example that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You get lot's of warnings because you are comparing values from different enums.

You can make a static function that return int for comparison:

```
template <int Size, typename T>
class Traits<Vector<Size, T>>
{
    enum {ElementCount = Size};

    static int GetElementCount() {return static_cast<int>(ElementCount);}
};
```